# How does population requirement work in Civilization VI?

Tags: civilization-6

I've read that "Each 3 Population in a city allows it to support an additional District.", however I've seen requirements such as 3, 6, 15, and 19. So kinda goes off the rails with divisible by three. Anyone sure?

*Note that the tooltips are off when I take screenshot - it is currently saying 10 pop required for theater.*

[image: Says I need 10 population for Theater]

Comment: My understanding and my experience in several games so far seem to confirm the each 3 pop = +1 district. (1 at 1, 2 at 4, 3 at 7, etc.)
Most probably something else affecting the requirements, any specifics or screenshots?

Comment: Unfortunately I started a new game without thinking to save the state of my old one where I was at the end. I'll be sure to come back and post anything in next playthrough.

Comment: Added screenshot :)

Comment: Well, you have 3 specialised district right now If I see correctly, which matches the limit of 3 district at 7 population. So you should unlock the next space at 10 pop and so on every 3 citizens.

Comment: So once I hit 10, how would one have 15? I am missing some math :D

Answer (score 2):

To be a bit more explicit with what the comments and Cornelius has said.

**Formula**

```
P = 3(d - 1) + 1
```

- `P` is the number of population.
- `d` is the number of specialty districts built in the city.

**Examples**

1. 1st district requires 1 population.
2. 2nd district requires 4 population.
3. 3rd district requires 7 population
4. and so on...

Answer (score 1):

While the law if three holds true in most cases, there are other factors that can influence the values e.g. some Civs get additional district bonuses etc.